# Best Django practice, filter ORM or python?

Tags: python, django

Multiple filters needs to be applied to a `QuerySet`. Should I query the database multiple times, or do the sorting/filtering in `Python`?

```
data = Data.objects.all()   
for f in somefilters:
    tempdata = data.filter(*f.args)
    # do work

or

data = list(Data.objects.all())
for f in somefilters:
    tempdata = filter(data, key=...)
    #do work
```

Comment: What do benchmarks say?

Comment: The database will most probably be able to filter faster, given you've designed it correctly - but try benching

Comment: Why aren't you using `.objects.get_queryset().filter(...)`?

Comment: the answer is: "it depends" ...but doing this `data = list(Data.objects.all())` is going to load the whole table into memory as instantiated model objects. probably a bad idea unless you know you will never have many objects in the `Data` table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have an absurd number of filters, you should probably just use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). That's what they're for.

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q()
for filter in filters:
    q |= Q(*f.args)
data = Data.objects.filter(q)

# Do things with `data`
```

Comment: upvoted. You can also use: `q = [Q(f.args) for f in filters]` and then `Data.objects.filter(*q)`

Comment: @Pynchia I'm pretty sure this will create a `AND` filter instead of a `OR` filter.

Comment: what does the problem require? Each filter appears to refine/shave the queryset.

Comment: @Pynchia The problem requires an or, because they want to do some work on each of the groups.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco how are they going to do that with your answer either? you are giving just a single queryset

Comment: @Anentropic Considering the question, they are assumedly doing something on each object. The question was about whether they should do the filtering in the DB (which is not obvious when using Django if you don't know about `Q` objects) or in Python, not about how to actually do the processing. I updated my question to hopefully make this clearer, but I can't know what the OP means to do with the data since they did not include this in their question.

Comment: it seems to me the `tempdata` variable indicates they want to do work on a series of unrelated filtered querysets

Comment: @Anentropic All right — that's your reading of their question, mine simply happens to be different (informed by the fact that they asked about **filtering**, not **grouping**).